# Как добавить подпись оси х. Matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

| lc_start_date | один | Два | Три | А | И | В | Ж | Мем | Др | Дом | Сто |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 01.06.2021 | 56 | 45 | 45 | 47 | 67 | 87 | 3 | 8 | 7 | 67 | 89 |
| 05.06.2021 | 58 | 67 | 45 | 47 | 67 | 87 | 3 | 8 | 7 | 67 | 89 |
| 06.06.2021 | 58 | 67 | 45 | 47 | 67 | 87 | 3 | 8 | 7 | 67 | 89 |
| 07.06.2021 | 58 | 67 | 45 | 47 | 67 | 87 | 3 | 8 | 7 | 67 | 89 |

Есть такой код:

```
df2.plot(figsize=(15,15), kind=‘line’, subplots=True, title=‘1’, layout=(4,3), sharex=False, sharey=False`,xlabel=‘date’)
```

Добавила xlabel=“Date”, но выводит ошибку:

> «Unknown property xlabel.
> [image: хочу заменить lc_start_date на даты или текст DATe]

Если без xlabel то пишет lc_start_date

Хочу убрать lc_start_date или переименовать в даты.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Я добавила в df2.plot(xlabel=‘date’). Но выдаёт ошибку. Делала на данных выгруженных с sql. Когда запускаю такой же код на данных из эксель все работает.

Comment: Еще раз - работайте с matplotlib напрямую. Ваша ошибка к типу данных не имеет никакого отношения. Приведите пример исходных данных в вопросе, если хотите, чтобы вам помогли разобраться.

Comment: Теперь понятнее ? Или что-то дополнить

Comment: `plt.xlabel(“Date”)`, если у вас, конечно, `matplotlib` импортирован стандартным образом

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Только сейчас понял, что дело в размерности массива холстов (axes).

Ваш код создает **двумерный** массив
Поэтому, скорее всего, работать будет следующий код:

```
cols = 3
rows = 4
axes = df.plot(figsize=(15,15), kind='line', subplots=True, title='1', layout=(rows, cols), sharex=False, sharey=False)

for x in range(cols-1):
    for y in range(rows-1):
        axes[x,y].set_xlabel(df.index[x+y])
```